# iOS 7 Newsstand default cover is not set

Tags: ios7, settings, newsstand-kit

Since iOS7 the default cover that is set in the info.plist under Icon Files (iOS 5) are not shown after installation the app. Instead the default cover by Apple is shown.

I can see that this property is for iOS 5 but I tried other as well. An example - Icon Files could not be changed from an Array to a Dictionary.

Do you know how to set a default cover for Newsstand app in iOS 7?

Best Regards!

Comment: Hello there i am facing same problem any solutions :) ! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i got the solution.Add `Icon files (iOS 5)` if you didnt add previously in your app-info.plist. Make sure that the long edge on your default cover is at least 512 px. ( Mine is 300 * 528 px)

Please see screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi! I still cannot do it and I tried your solution before. It works without a problem on iOS6 but iOS7 still gives me the crappy default image :/

Comment: After a long fight and much tests, I finally found somewhere that was said that it's nice to omit the .png in giving the name of the file ;) So it would be "yourcovericonhere" only. Hope that helps somebody else as well!

Answer (score 1):

check the references for the icons you are using in the .plist, make sure they are added as reference to the image and not as references to a folder like the references for the launch images and the icon images

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "App Icons Source" catalog.  In Target=>"General" tab.