# How to specify newsstand icon for iOS 7 in .plist?

Tags: ios7, icons, plist, newsstand-kit

Hello everyone I am trying to specify newsstand icon for iOS 7.0. Where should i specify it in the app .plist file. I have Icon Files ( iOS 5) set for the newsstand shelf icon, and its working perfectly under iPad iOS 6.1 but not under iOS 7.0 .

Comment: I posted the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20504874/1642881 , hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

check the references to the icons, make sure you are adding the image you will be using as icons as a separate reference, if you are adding a folder the icons wont display.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "App Icons Source" catalog. In Target=>"General" tab.